# Detecting an in-flight request to an API in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a service in Nodejs in which I fetch prices from an Api and the call to the API might take over a minute so one of the things that can happen is that a request for a specific item can happen and the same item can be requested before the first item is returned and
I want to detect if there is an in-flight request for a specified item and, if there is one, I need to wait for this request to be finished and return the same response for both requests.

An example diagram would be:

```
00.000 getCost('123') #1 call
00.001 getExternalCost('123') query
01.000 getCost('123') #2 call
90.001 getExternalCost('123') response
90.002 getCost('123') #1 response
90.003 getCost('123') #2 response
```

This is the code I have written so far, which simply fetches the cost of the item.

```
let cache = new Map();
let addToCache = (key,val) => {
  if(!cache.has(key)){
    cache.set(key,val);
  }
}

const getCost = async (itemId) => {

  if(cache.has(itemId)){
    return cache.get(itemId);
  }

  const price = await getExternalCost(itemId);
  addToCache(itemId,price);
  
  return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done if you add promises to the cache rather than awaiting them. By doing this an incoming query can be redirected to receive the value of a similar query pending in the cache.

```js
const MAX_AGE = 1000;
const cache = new Map();

const cacheContainsKey = key => {
  if (!cache.has(key)) {
    return false;
  }

  const {
    _ts
  } = cache.get(key);
  const age = Date.now() - _ts;
  if (age <= MAX_AGE) {
    return true;
  }

  console.log(`key ${key} age exceeds MAX_AGE: ${age}. Deleting key from cache.`);
  cache.delete(key);
  return false;
};

const addToCache = (key, val) => {
  cache.set(key, {
    _ts: Date.now(),
    val
  });
};

const retrieveFromCache = async(itemId) => {
  try {
    const start = Date.now();
    const price = await cache.get(itemId).val;
    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Query for ${itemId}. Price: ${price}. Time spent: ${(end - start) / 1000} seconds.`);
    return price;
  } catch (err) {
    /*
      If required insert logic here to remove the itemId from the cache to
      allow new attempts to getExternalCost on this itemId.
    */
    return err;
  }
};

const getCost = async(itemId) => {
  if (cacheContainsKey(itemId)) {
    const price = await retrieveFromCache(itemId);
    return price;
  }

  const pricePromise = getExternalCost(itemId);
  addToCache(itemId, pricePromise);

  // all queries go through the cache
  const price = await retrieveFromCache(itemId);
  return price;
};


// example code
function getExternalCost(itemId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, __reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(itemId * 100);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

let counter = 0;
const itemIds = [10, 10, 12, 12, 10, 1];

// mimic incoming queries
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  getCost(itemIds[counter++]);
  if (counter === itemIds.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I've seen this problem solved before.  Cache the promise and let any caller looking for a value that has a promise just use the `promise.then()` or `await promise` to get the value.

Comment: What if the first request of a kind returns a promise that rejects (due to a temporary error)? All subsequent hits to the cache will also return the rejected promise.

Comment: @jsejcksn That's a good point. Something would need to be set up to periodically clean the cache. Alternatively, some logic could be added in specifically to handle that in a `try/catch` for the call to `retrieveFromCache`. Some care would have to be done though as it could easily just hammer against an endpoint that is failing and will not give different results - which a cache can help protect. This part depends entirely on the context.

Comment: @jsejcksn Adjusted answer where the cache could be updated based on a failed query.

Comment: @jsejcksn - When a promise rejects, you remove it from the cache at the point you see it rejected - the cache code itself can also monitor the promise and do that.  If multiple requests were waiting on that promise, they will all see the rejection.  It seems like you can't have it both ways.  Either you share in-flight requests by sharing the promise and share results and error or you don't.  That seems like the right way to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree (according to the criteria and code in the question) that all requesters awaiting a pending response for the same resource should receive the same response. But it doesn't have to be that way, and you can "have it both ways" by managing fulfillment of the request queue separately from the cache.

Comment: @jsejcksn I was thinking back over this and found a simple adjustment to incorporate some of the cache management automatically. If we change the cache value to also include a timestamp of when it was entered, then it can be easily compared against some given `MAX_AGE` value applied to all cache entries. This should remove any error response for a key if sufficient time has passed to attempt a retry.